# AWS Airflow S3 Key Sensor not triggering

Tags: amazon-s3, airflow

I am using AWS Airflow Managed Worflows(MWAA) which basically works like a charm for all the tasks except for s3keysensor . For some strange reasons , the task never gets triggered . I have created an S3 connection from the airflow UI called **s3_conn** which is being passed as a parameter in the task . Below is the code

```
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators import BashOperator, S3KeySensor
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from airflow.utils.dates import days_ago


default_args = {
    'owner': 'airflow',
    'depends_on_past': False,
    'start_date': days_ago(1),
    'email': ['sid@gmail.com'],
    'email_on_failure': False,
    'email_on_retry': False,
    'retries': 5,
    'retry_delay': timedelta(minutes=5)
}

dag = DAG('siddag', default_args=default_args, schedule_interval= '@once')

t1 = BashOperator(
    task_id='bash_test',
    bash_command='echo "hello, it should work" > order_items.csv',
    dag=dag)

sensor = S3KeySensor(
    task_id='s3_sensor_test',
    bucket_key='s3://bucket_name/data/order_items-*',
    wildcard_match=True,
    bucket_name='bucket_name',
    s3_conn_id='s3_conn',
    timeout=18*60*60,
    poke_interval=10,
    dag=dag)

t1.set_upstream(sensor)
```

The Task logs do not show anything and task status says "Not yet started" . The file does exist the bucket inside the **data** folder . I have even tried updating the file to see if this gets triggered and also , the Airflow has sufficient permissions for s3  . Any help would be appreciated .

Comment: Please try to test with the S3KeySensor from providers. You are using the deprecated version of the code. https://pypi.org/project/apache-airflow-backport-providers-amazon/